# Discrete DDR3 Layout Check

Tags: layout, signal-integrity, ddr3

I have 8 chips of 512 Mb DDR3 interfaced with the processor with point to point Data & fly by Address/command topology.

I need to remove 1 DDR3 & keep it unmount. The rest 7 DDRs should work normally. Which DDR chip, I should remove from communication or signal Integrity prospective.

Comment: Often, the datasheet of the controller tells you the minimal and maximal segment length/delay between controller and first chip, between chips and between last chip and termination. I would say as long as you don't exceed these with a chip missing somewhere, you should be safe from that point of view.

The other question is if the controller supports the new data width and if so, does it care which data lines are missing?

What controller/CPU/FPGA are you using?

Comment: 1st chip should be the choice...

Comment: I am using NXP P2020 processor.

Comment: @Oshi I can't access the datasheet of the P2020. Have you checked that your configuration with 7 chips is supported?

Comment: @Oshi: The datasheet tells under 8.5.1: The data path to individual physical banks is 64 or 32 bits wide, 72 or 40 bits with ECC. With seven devices, you will get 56-bit width when using x8 devices

Comment: @Manu- I understand that. But datasheet does not say that it wont support 56 bit width. 64 or 32  bit is standard configuration. I dont think any datasheet will tell that we can reduce data bus width. That is point 1.                                                                                        Point 2 is lets suppose I have that option. Now, from SI point of view, which DDR chip should be preferably removed.

Comment: @Oshi Fair enough, it may drive the person adapting the bootloader and stuff crazy. From the SI standpoint it probably won't even matter that much which one you will remove. As you are removing the stub caused by the lines inside the chip, so there shouldn't even be much negative effects. Also you have less loading off the bus with one chip less. I would chose either the first or the last. If in doubt, simulate or experiment.